# How to delete a single Blob file with Azure SDK for Java v12?

Tags: java, kotlin, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-for-java

How do you delete a single Blob file with the Azure SDK v12 for Java?
This is what i tried so far. But it doesn't work.

Btw the sample code is Kotlin:

```
val blobServiceClient: BlobServiceAsyncClient by lazy {
    BlobServiceClientBuilder()
        .endpoint(blobProperties.endpoint)
        .sasToken(blobProperties.sasToken)
        .buildAsyncClient()
}

val containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerAsyncClient(blobProperties.containerName)

val blobName = "test.jpg"

val imageClient = containerClient.getBlobAsyncClient(blobName).blockBlobAsyncClient
val deleteImage = imageClient.delete()
println(deleteImage)
```

We are using the library "azure-storage-blob-12.4.0.jar"

Comment: What do you mean when you say `But it doesn't work.`? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No i don't get any errors. Response is a MonoFlatMap without any meaningful content. But by checking the container in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer i see that the files still exist.

Comment: Can you try changing the following code `imageClient.delete()` to `imageClient.delete().doOnSuccess(response -> System.out.println("Completed delete"));`?

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work for me. I didn't even get a response with all doOn* functions. I think the problem was, that the script didn't even wait until there was a response, so nothing was fired. Anyway it pushed me to search in the right direction. So thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end a simple `block()` was what worked for me which causes the MonoFlatMap to block indefinitely until a next signal is received.

```
containerClient.getBlobAsyncClient(blobName).delete().block()
```

If you want to read further information about block() you can find it here:
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--